# Disjunction in algebraic semantics for intuitionistic predicate logic

Tags: logic, model-theory, constructive-mathematics

I'm trying to understand the chapter (13) on algebraic semantics for intuitionistic predictate logic in *Constructivism in Mathematics* by Troelstra and van Dalen and I'm having trouble verifying soundness.

The models we are discussing are so-called $\Omega$-models which take truth values in some complete Heyting algebra $\Omega$.

Proving soundness can be, according to the authors, done in a routine way. If I'm correct that means by induction on the structure of derivations. If the final rule application of a derivation is of the form

$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma_1 \vdash A_1, \ldots, \Gamma_n \vdash A_n \\ \hline
\Gamma \vdash A
\end{align}
$$
then our induction hypothesis is: in each $\Omega$-model we have that if for some $i$ it holds that $[\![B]\!] = \top$ for all $B \in \Gamma_i$, then $[\![A_i]\!] = \top$.

Now consider for instance the case of disjunction elimination. We have a derivation of the form 
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma_1 \vdash A \lor B & & \Gamma_2, A \vdash C & & \Gamma_3, B \vdash C \\ \hline 
\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \cup \Gamma_3 \vdash C
\end{align}
$$
Now suppose that in some $\Omega$-model we have that for each sentence $B$ in $\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \cup \Gamma_3$, it holds that $[\![B]\!] = \top$. Then by the induction hypothesis we have $[\![A \lor B]\!] = [\![A]\!] \lor [\![B]\!]= \top$. The result would follow easily if that would imply that in the same model we have either $[\![A]\!] = \top$ or $[\![B]\!] = \top$, but I don't think that holds for every complete Heyting algebra. Because of this I don't know how to proceed.

I feel like my trouble is caused by some fundamental misunderstanding of either $\Omega$-models or Heyting algebra's, but I don't know exactly what I'm missing.

Could anybody point me in the right direction? If more definitions or explanation is needed I'd be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Gamma = A_1,\ldots,A_n$, then define $[\![ \Gamma ]\!]$ to be $[\![ A_1 ]\!] \wedge \ldots \wedge [\![ A_n ]\!]$, and in particular take the empty sequent to $\top$. Then show that if $\Gamma \vdash A$, then $[\![ \Gamma ]\!] \leq [\![A ]\!]$. This can be done by induction on derivation. Once you've done that you can deduce that if $\Gamma \vdash A$ and $[\![ \Gamma ]\!] = \top$ then $[\![ A ]\!] = \top$, but as you've noticed this is too weak to do directly by induction. Eg for a non trivial topological space $T$ there will be open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U \cup V = T$ but $U \neq T$ and $V \neq T$.